# Why did I just get a large drop in reputation on this question?

Tags: support

I was just looking at my reputation and noticed I received a -10 recently for [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/242750/88313).

When I look at the actual answer there's no downvotes.  I also looked at [the answer history](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/242750/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries) and don't see anything that stands-out to indicate why such a big drop in points.

I thought it could be that a user, or users, who upvoted were removed and so the points I received from them were removed, too.  But 10 points seems like a really high number for this sort of situation.

I looked in the Help Center but couldn't find anything to lead me to an explanation for a large drop like this.  Can one of the Mods please let me know what happened here?

[image]

Comment: You get 10 points for an upvote, so a removed user results in -10. For a more detailed look I need to get back to a Mac first, analysis on an iPhone is cumbersome...

Comment: Thanks, @nohillside, it looks like monomeeth got the answer for me.

Comment: Having nearly 19k rep you call -10 a "large drop"? :> Some years ago, I've had some user upvoting many of my questions in stackoverflow.com and got -200 or -300 when that user was removed from the system! :>

Comment: @trejder Yes, I call it a large drop.  While I understand I might not seem large to you, it is large to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have looked into this for you and it seems this is the result of someone reversing their upvote. See image below:

[image]

So, because this was an unupvote as opposed to an actual downvote, it doesn't appear as a downvote on your answer.

Seems to be a case of a user having changed their mind for some reason some time after having originally upvoted your answer.

Comment: Great, thanks for helping me out on this.